# Counting the number of times a substring occurs in a string using strlen+substr+strpos ONLY PHP

Tags: php, string, substr, strpos, strlen

I would like to write a function that can count the number of times a substring occurs in a string using strlen+substr+strpos ONLY ,in PHP.

Without using `substr_count`!

example: `fn('iwritecodeiwritecode-','i');`

Thanks Ahead

Comment: Dont teachers come up with some narly bits of homework

Comment: But as you have not even attempted anything we cannot help because SO is not a place to get your homework done for you. If you try something and have problems, then ask a specific question about a specific issue you are having. We are more than willing tou help  a tryer

Comment: php string can also be treated as array .

Comment: You just need strpos and a loop. Not that hard, but If you dont have concrete questions, we cant help you

Answer (score 1):

You will not need `strlen()` or `substr()` for this task.

Merely iterate your string with a while loop, advance the output of `strpos()` with every successful found needle and count the number of successful matches.

The "magic" in this technique is using the previous `strpos()` value (plus 1) as the the starting point for all subsequent `strpos()` calls.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/417c1a1638170f51d011f8381fac59e5370ca2c0))

```
function countSubstrings($haystack,$needle) {
    $pos = -1;  // start at -1 so that first iteration uses $pos of 0 as starting offset
    $tally = 0;
    while (($pos = strpos($haystack, $needle, ++$pos)) !== false) {
        ++$tally;
    }
    return $tally;
}
echo countSubstrings('iwritecodeiwritecodeiwritecode', 'i');  // 6
echo countSubstrings('iwritecodeiwritecodeiwritecode', 'Perumal');  // 0
echo countSubstrings('iwritecodeiwritecodeiwritecode', 'write');  // 3
```

> A note to future readers, this question is not best practice.  The correct method would be a simple call of the pre-existing php function `substr_count()`.
>
> ```
> echo substr_count('iwritecodeiwritecodeiwritecode', 'i');
> ```
>
> Or, less efficient versus `substring_count()` would be `preg_match_all()` which returns the number of matches.
>
> ```
> echo preg_match_all('/i/', 'iwritecodeiwritecodeiwritecode'); // 6
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
function fn($string, $char){ 
    $count=0;
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($string);$i++){
        if($string[$i] == $char){
            $count++;
        } 
    }
    print($count);
}

fn('iwritecodeiwritecode-','i');
```

I hope it helps Cheers!

Comment: Congratulations on doing someone's homework, it's really "nice" of you. I just wonder, will the OP even bother to give you imaginary internet points for this, given the fact he/she saw it and didn't even bother to upvote you. Homework beggars should be ignored, and while your answer is correct, you just wasted your time to help someone who won't even appreciate it.

Comment: I appreciate you for your answer. I noticed there is something you need to add in your code. That is, it only works for a single character. What if the user passes two or more characters in the function?

Comment: @Mjh what do you suggest pseudo code or no help at all for such question? Do me one more favor and link me the SO terms/rules/conditions that don't allow me to answer such question or of any specific type thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with my own best solution.

```
<?php

    $str = "iwritecodeiwritecode";

    function find_substr_count($str, $substr) {
        $substr_len = strlen($substr);
        $substr_count = 0;
        for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
            $substr_temp = '';
            for($j = $i; $j < $i + $substr_len; $j++) {
                if($j < strlen($str)) {
                    $substr_temp .= $str[$j];
                }
            }

            if($substr_temp == $substr) {
                $substr_count += 1;
            }
        }

        return $substr_count;
    }

    echo find_substr_count($str, "i");

?>
```

It doesn't only work for single character. You can also try passing two or more characters in the function like:

`echo find_substr_count($str, "write");`

I've given my best to help you.

Hope it helps!